# Cross product in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'd like to perform the expensive operation of cross product across two data sets in Hadoop using Java MapReduce.

For example, I have records from data set A and data set B, and I'd like each record in data set A to be matched up to each record in data set B in the output. I realize that the output size of this would be `|A| * |B|`, but want to do it anyways.

I see that Pig has [`CROSS`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#cross) but am unaware of how it is implemented at a high-level. Perhaps I will go take a look at the source code.

Not looking for any code, just want to know at a high-level how I should approach this problem.

Comment: Can you fit all of A, or all of B, into one worker's memory? Then it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @SeanOwen I wish! Unfortunately, this is not the case. One approach I was thinking was splitting up data set B into ~10-100 or so splits, then running 10-100 different mr jobs at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similar when looking at document similarity (comparing a document to every other document) and ended up with a custom input format that splits up the two datasets and then ensured there was a 'split' for each subset of data.

So your splits would look like (each merging two sets of 10 records, outputting 100 records)

```
A(1-10) x B(1-10)
A(11-20) x B(1-10)
A(21-30) x B(1-10)
A(1-10) x B(11-20)
A(11-20) x B(11-20)
A(21-30) x B(11-20)
A(1-10) x B(21-30)
A(11-20) x B(21-30)
A(21-30) x B(21-30)
```

I don't remember how performant it was though, but had a document set in the size order of thousands to compare against one another (on an 8 node dev cluster), with millions of cross products calculated.

I could also make improvements to the algorithm as some documents would never score well against others (if they had too much temporal time between them for example), and generate better splits as a result.

Comment: This is fantastic. Very clean as it all of the pairing up is done by the input format. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Thats wonderful approach. I was wondering if you can share how you wrote "custom input format" or may be code. That would be helpful.

Comment: @justinwaugh - I'll see if i can dig something out and write a blog post on it, i'll be sure to link it from here

Comment: @ChrisWhite I was asking this about my book MapReduce design patterns, and after looking at a few implementations of this I decided this was the best. Check it out at the end of the Joins chapter. Hit me up via email if you want me to send you a copy.