# How to design a MapReduce model for merge two text files

Tags: hadoop, merge, mapreduce

For example I have two files, A and B. Both of them are text files.

A contains one line text like this:

```
I'm A
```

And B contains three lines text like this:

```
I'm B1
I'm B2
I'm B3
```

My exception is to add the only line of A to the front of each line of B, so the result will be:

```
I'm A I'm B1
I'm A I'm B2
I'm A I'm B3
```

The hard part for me is how to understand the parameters of MapReduce job. In the traditional function, I can let A and B be the two parameters, then merge them in my rule. Some pseudo-codes like this:

```
// Two parameters, A and B
public void merge(File A, File B) {
    String lineA = A.firstLine;
    for (Each lineB in B) {
        String result = lineA + " " + lineB;
        File.wirte(result, "ResultFile", appended);
    }
}
```

But in MapReduce stage, there doesn't have "traditional parameters", for exmaple:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
    String line = value.toString();
    try {
        context.write(new Text(line), new Text(""));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I understand that the above codes will read the files line by line, use each line as key and set value as empty, then write the key-value pair to file.

But again, the above mapper codes doesn't have traditional parameters, and I don't how to perform my logic of merge string, and write the result out.

The following is the pseudo-code of what I'm thinking now, am I have the correct design or I'm in a wrong direction? How should I design the MapReduce job? Some sample codes will be great helpful!

```
// I think I should pass in two Files
// So I can merge the line of them
public void map(File A, File B, Context context) {
    String key = A.firstLine();
    for (each LineB in B) {
        String value = key + " " + lineB;
    }
    try {
        context.write(new Text(""), value);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cross join - joining each record in A to each record in B. Luckily this is a pretty well-covered MapReduce design pattern.

The solution depends on how large your dataset is. If A or B can fit into memory, you're in luck. Simply add either of them to the DistributedCache and only read the other into a mapper. You don't even need a reducer for this!

If both datasets are large, your solution would have to involve writing a custom input split that would guarantee each set of data to be output enough times to match with all blocks from the other set. See [Cross product in MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365948/cross-product-in-mapreduce) - this example is also included in the book MapReduce Design Patterns.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have the clear design pattern and the book you recommend is great helpful!